# Callback was already called. But I never call callback before that. A bug in async.parallel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

I have done much research on this issue over internet still could not know the cause of the issue.

The issue is, when I use parallel function from async library, I am getting an error:

```
Callback was already called.
```

Here is my code: (I have commented on the line where I get this error)

```
var sendNotificationAddToMyRememberNew = function(request, response, restaurant) {

    async.parallel({
        notification_list: function (callback) {
            models.NotificationList.create({
                alert_msg: "Restaurant " + restaurant.name + " remembered.",
                payload: JSON.stringify({
                    restaurant_id: restaurant.id,
                    restaurant_name: restaurant.name,
                    restaurant_image: restaurant.image
                }),
                type: constants.NOTIFICATION_TYPE.RESTAURANT_REMEMBERED,
                platform_type: constants.MOBILE_PLATFORM_TYPE.ALL,
                status: constants.NOTIFICATION_STATUS.SENT,
                device_token: null,
                device_arn: null,
                schedule_time: moment.utc(),
                customer_id: request.token.customer_id,
                customer_email: request.token.email,
                created_date: moment.utc(),
                updated_date: moment.utc()
            }).then(function(notificationList){
                callback(null, notificationList);
            }).catch(function(error){
                callback(error);
            });
        },
        badge_count: function(callback) {

            models.CustomerBadgeCount.findOrCreate({
                where: {
                    customer_id: request.token.customer_id
                },
                defaults: {
                    badge_count: 1,
                    customer_id: request.token.customer_id,
                    created_date: moment.utc(),
                    updated_date: moment.utc()
                }
            }).spread(function (badgeCount, created) {
                if(!created){
                    badgeCount.update(
                        {
                            badge_count: badgeCount.badge_count + 1,
                            updated_date: moment.utc()
                        },
                        {
                            fields:[
                                "badge_count",
                                "updated_date"
                            ]
                        }
                    ).then(function(badgeCount) {
                        callback(null, badgeCount);
                    }).catch(function (error) {
                        callback(error); // Getting error of callback here
                    });
                }else{
                    callback(null, badgeCount)
                }
            }).catch(function (error) {
                callback(error);
            });

        },
        devices: function(callback) {
            models.CustomerDeviceTokens.findAll({
                where: {
                    customer_email: request.token.email
                }
            }).then(function(devices) {
                callback(null, devices);
            }).catch(function(error) {
                callback(error);
            });
        }
    }, function(error, results){

        if(error) {
            Logger.logDbError(error,request);
            return console.log(error);
        }
        //callback function
        console.log("-------------------------------------------------------");
        console.log("Notification List: " + JSON.stringify(results.notification_list, null, 4));
        console.log("badge_count: " + JSON.stringify(results.badge_count, null, 4));

        if(results.devices && result.devices.count > 0) {
            results.devices.forEach(function(device) {
                console.log("device_arn: " + device.device_arn);
            }, this);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Don't use async.js with promises. Plain `Promise.all` is so much easier.

Comment: @Bergi This question is not duplicate. I have solved this question. Please take a look at my answer.

Comment: The duplicate explains the [difference between `.then(…, …)` and `.then(…).catch(…)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24662289/1048572) which is the cause for getting `callback` called twice.

Comment: if you feel that this question is duplicate then please delete it. Beacause I cannot delete it as this question already has answers.

Comment: @Bergi sorry, I forgot to mention your name in above comment. Please read it.

Comment: I can't delete it either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `findOrCreate` method of sequelize in my code. The original syntax of findOrCreate is :

```
model.SomeModelName.findOrCreate({
    ....
    ....
}).spread(function(data, created) {

}).fail(function(err) {

});
```

As you can see in above code that `.spread()` should be followed by `.fail()`, But in my code, I used `.spread()` followed by `.catch()`.
So, both the blocks were executed and thus **callback was called twice**

Comment: That might be how you get the exception inside the `then`, but it's not the actual issue.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if `callback(null, badgeCount)` throws an error (which could happen if the final callback throws an error for some reason).

What happens in that case is that the `.catch` handler is called, in which you call `callback` again, resulting in the *"already called"* message.

To prevent this (or rather, to catch these errors), you shouldn't use `.catch` but use the two-argument version of `.then`:

```
.then(function(badgeCount) {
  callback(null, badgeCount);
}, function (error) {
  callback(error);
});
```

(and similar for all other locations in your code where you use `.then().catch()` inside an `async` operation)

Comment: Good answer!!!!!! But I have figured it out. I will post another one. Thanks for the answer and your time.